# .htaccess deny from domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, dns

I'm using the following code to try to restrict access to a site, but it just isn't allowing me to connect from the referral domain.

```
<Limit GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from studiorenegade.com
</limit>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(_app) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(_config) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(_content) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).yml$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).yaml$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.git+ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]

AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile /var/www/{path to .htpassword}  
require valid-user
```

This all seems so simple that I can't seem to configure the allow correctly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This like:

```
allow from studiorenegade.com
```

allows connections *directly* from the server at `studiorenegade.com`, not the people who have browsed to the site and clicked on a link (which would be Allow from ). You've essentially denied access from everyone except someone who's using the serer that studiorenegade.com is at.

You probably want to get rid of that and add this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?studiorenegade\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://hostname.of.your.server.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

right below the `RewriteEngine On` line.

This sends any request whose referer header field isn't from "`studiorenegade.com`". However, this field can be forged and isn't a guarantee that people won't be able to still access your site from other places.